# Conventions for notation of function exponentation.

Tags: exponentiation, function-and-relation-composition

I read a previous question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24449/conventions-for-function-notation) but it seems incomplete for me (missing references).

Given a generic function, $ f $ :
 1. is true that $ f^2 $ means $ f^2(x) = (f \circ f)(x) = f(f(x)) $ ?
 2. or is true that $ f^2 $ means $ f^2(x) = (f(x))^2 $ ?

With your answers can you write also some references?
Anyway if (2) holds, then is $ (f \circ f)(x) $ the only way to write $ f(f(x)) $ ?
Instead, if (1) holds, then why do some books write $ \ln^2(x) = (\ln(x))^2 $ or the trigonometric identity $ \sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x) = 1 $ ?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: It is often used in both ways (just not in the same context). You'll simply have to determine which is intended from the situation.

Comment: I'ld also suggest you to read the answer given here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30317/arcsin-written-as-sin-1x as it is quite well written

Comment: If you want an opinion on that, here is mine: Use $f^n(x) := (f(x))^n$ only if $f$ is a standard function. It is very common for trigonometric and hyperbolical functions, but that's about it.

Comment: thanks for answers. Filmor brought a good argument (even if i'm a Gauss fan here xD ) and now i'm reading the link about arcsin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen both.  I seem to recall having read somewhere (Therefore it's true!  Right?) that Gauss objected to writing $\sin^2 x$ for $(\sin x)^2$ on the grounds that $\sin^2x$ ought to mean $\sin\sin x$.  I'm inclined to agree with Gauss, but then there's King Canute and all that.

Certainly using $f^2$ to mean $f\circ f$ is consistent with the usual notation by which $f^{-1}$ means the inverse function.

Comment: I inclined to agree with Gauss too :P