# Notation of a function raised to a power

Tags: functions, notation, exponentiation

$f(x)^2$ is sometimes written as $f^2(x)$.

Why is it not written as $f(x)^2$?

Is it just a matter of taste or convention?

Comment: It is worth pointing out that $f^2$ is somewhat ambiguous whether we are talking about $f\cdot f$ or if we are talking about $f\circ f$, just as $f^{-1}$ is ambiguous whether we are talking about the multiplicative inverse of $f$ or the functional inverse of $f$.  Better to avoid it in my opinion.

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208363/conventions-for-notation-of-function-exponentation?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because the notation could make it clear that the function is $f^2=f\cdot f$. That is, if $g=f^2=f\cdot f,$ then we'd write $g(x)=f^2(x).$ Writing $f(x)^2$ kind of hides the functional relationship. Although, as noted in the comments, writing $f^2(x)$ could be confused with composition. It's probably best to clarify what you mean when you write it. You could also write $(f(x))^2,$ which has a pretty clear meaning.